# Building Chat App with Angularjs and Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, facebook-chat

using angularfire seed i would like to know if there is any **tutorials** about making a **private chat between users** something like in facebook. you pic a user and then you can chat with him.

please let me know about any resources in this topic. using firebase and angularjs.

Comment: If you want open source approach, you can try researching on websocket library like Socket.io and persist the data using MongoDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to check out this great tutorial by [`thinkster.io`](https://thinkster.io/)

> [Learn to build a Real-Time Slack clone with AngularFire](https://thinkster.io/angularfire-slack-tutorial/)